# Kendo UI grid with MVC fails to use Template when ajax turned on

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using KendoUI with MVC.NET to create a grid. The data source for the grid is an AJAX call back to my controller.

The TEMPLATE property on bound columns should allow me to format the columns with RAZOR templating.

This works until I "turn" on ajax. The code below illustrates the issue:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@model IEnumerable<Test>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test - Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@{
        //public class Test {
        //    public string A;
        //    public string B;
        //}

        var data = new List<Test>() { new Test() { A="a1", B="b1"}, new Test() { A="a2",B="b2"}};

        // This one fails to honor TEMPLATE
        Html.Kendo().Grid(data).Name("test").Columns(columns => {
                                                              columns.Bound("A").Template(@<div>@item.A TEMPLATE APPLIED</div>);
                                                              columns.Bound("B");
                                                          }).DataSource(ds=>ds.Ajax()).Render(); // THIS BREAKS IT!

        // This one honors template               
        Html.Kendo().Grid(data).Name("test").Columns(columns => {
                                                              columns.Bound("A").Template(@<div>@item.A TEMPLATE APPLIED</div>);
                                                              columns.Bound("B");
                                                          }).Render();


    }
```

Two grids are displayed in this sample. The second grid does razor templating ok. The first fails to show the templatized data. The first grid just shows the original data.

NOTE: I've simplified this code as much as possible to illustrate the problem. Normally, after calling the Ajax() method, I also call other methods to setup the callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-customize-the-way-a-property-is-displayed-in-a-grid-bound-column?), for Ajax datasource you should use `ClientTemplate` instead of `Template`. Be careful, the syntax is slightly different :

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(data).Name("test").Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound("A").ClientTemplate("<div>#=A# TEMPLATE APPLIED</div>");
    columns.Bound("B").ClientTemplate("<div>#=A# AND #=B# JUST FOR KICKS</div>");;
}).DataSource(ds=>ds.Ajax()).Render();
```

Comment: I had tried that, but I guess what I want is a way to apply use razor syntax in the templates. I really don't like the standard kendoui templating.